# What is the best way to save numpy arrays of different length to the same csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, pandas

I am working with 1d numpy arrays, first doing some math then saving everything to a single csv file.  The data sets are often of different lengths and I cannot flatten them together. This is the best I could come up with but there must be a more elegant way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os


array1 = np.linspace(1,20,10)
array2 = np.linspace(12,230,10)
array3 = np.linspace(7,82,20)
array4 = np.linspace(6,55,20)

output1 = np.column_stack((array1.flatten(),array2.flatten())) #saving first array set to file 
np.savetxt("tempfile1.csv", output1, delimiter=',')
output2 = np.column_stack((array3.flatten(),array4.flatten())) # doing it again second array
np.savetxt("tempfile2.csv", output2, delimiter=',')
a = pd.read_csv('tempfile1.csv')                               # use pandas to read both files
b = pd.read_csv("tempfile2.csv")
merged = b.join(a, rsuffix='*')                                # merge with panda for single file
os.remove('tempfile1.csv')
os.remove("tempfile2.csv")                                     # delete temp files
merged.to_csv('savefile.csv', index=False)                     # save merged file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find a nice solution using `numpy.savetxt`, and there is probably a simpler `pandas` solution than yours, but in this case, a solution using the standard libraries `csv` and `itertools` is pretty concise:

```
In [45]: import csv

In [46]: from itertools import izip_longest   # Use zip_longest in Python 3.

In [47]: rows = izip_longest(array3, array4, array1, array2, fillvalue='')

In [48]: with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
   ....:     csv.writer(f).writerows(rows)
   ....:     

In [49]: !cat out.csv
7.0,6.0,1.0,12.0
10.947368421052632,8.5789473684210531,3.1111111111111112,36.222222222222221
14.894736842105264,11.157894736842106,5.2222222222222223,60.444444444444443
18.842105263157894,13.736842105263158,7.3333333333333339,84.666666666666657
22.789473684210527,16.315789473684212,9.4444444444444446,108.88888888888889
26.736842105263158,18.894736842105264,11.555555555555555,133.11111111111111
30.684210526315788,21.473684210526315,13.666666666666668,157.33333333333331
34.631578947368425,24.05263157894737,15.777777777777779,181.55555555555554
38.578947368421055,26.631578947368421,17.888888888888889,205.77777777777777
42.526315789473685,29.210526315789473,20.0,230.0
46.473684210526315,31.789473684210527,,
50.421052631578945,34.368421052631575,,
54.368421052631575,36.94736842105263,,
58.315789473684205,39.526315789473685,,
62.263157894736842,42.10526315789474,,
66.21052631578948,44.684210526315788,,
70.15789473684211,47.263157894736842,,
74.10526315789474,49.842105263157897,,
78.05263157894737,52.421052631578945,,
82.0,55.0,,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `concat` and pass param `axis=1`, to append the arrays as columns:

```
In [49]:

array1 = np.linspace(1,20,10)
array2 = np.linspace(12,230,10)
array3 = np.linspace(7,82,20)
array4 = np.linspace(6,55,20)

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(array1), pd.DataFrame(array2), pd.DataFrame(array3), pd.DataFrame(array4)], axis=1)
Out[49]:
            0           0          0          0
0    1.000000   12.000000   7.000000   6.000000
1    3.111111   36.222222  10.947368   8.578947
2    5.222222   60.444444  14.894737  11.157895
3    7.333333   84.666667  18.842105  13.736842
4    9.444444  108.888889  22.789474  16.315789
5   11.555556  133.111111  26.736842  18.894737
6   13.666667  157.333333  30.684211  21.473684
7   15.777778  181.555556  34.631579  24.052632
8   17.888889  205.777778  38.578947  26.631579
9   20.000000  230.000000  42.526316  29.210526
10        NaN         NaN  46.473684  31.789474
11        NaN         NaN  50.421053  34.368421
12        NaN         NaN  54.368421  36.947368
13        NaN         NaN  58.315789  39.526316
14        NaN         NaN  62.263158  42.105263
15        NaN         NaN  66.210526  44.684211
16        NaN         NaN  70.157895  47.263158
17        NaN         NaN  74.105263  49.842105
18        NaN         NaN  78.052632  52.421053
19        NaN         NaN  82.000000  55.000000
```

then you can write this out to a csv like normal

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(array1), pd.DataFrame(array2), pd.DataFrame(array3), pd.DataFrame(array4)], axis=1).to_csv('savefile.csv', index=False)
```